# How to display an array dynamically

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to create a function that displays the following:

```
if number is between 0 - 5 then display values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
if number is between 5 - 10 then display values 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
if number is between 10 - 50 then display values 10, 20, 30, 40, 50
if number is between 50 - 100 then display values 20, 40, 60, 80, 100
if number is between 100 - 500 then display values 100, 200, 300, 400, 500
if number is between 500 - 1000 then display values 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000
if number is between 1000 - 5000 then display values 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000
```

and so on...

I'm thinking of working with 2 arrays and then multiply with 10.

```
int *MyFunct(int number) {

    int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int b[5] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };


    if (number >= 0 && number <= 5) {       
        return a;
    }   
    else if (number > 5 && number <= 10) {
        return b;
    }
    else if (number > 10 && number <= 50) {
        a[1] *= 10;
        a[2] *= 10;
        a[3] *= 10;
        a[4] *= 10;
        a[5] *= 10;
    }   
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Is there any possibility to do this dynamically or simpler?

Comment: Homework?______

Comment: You have conflicting ranges here. 0-5 *and* 5-10? You can't have 5 in both.

Comment: Returning a pointer to a local array is undefined behavior. The returned pointer will be used by the time the data it points to is already destroyed. Your program is very likely to crash.

Comment: There's a big problem in the code as well. The way you access the individual elements of the array is incorrect. It should be    `a[0] *= 10; a[1] *= 10;`  i.e...It should start from `0` and not `1`.

Comment: Also, `a[5]` does not exist in your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first note that you cannot return an automatic array. For this use case, the simplest is to just use static ones.

Then your algorithm can be reworded as:

- start with the array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
- if the number is less than the last number of the array, return the array
- else multiply the array alternatively by 2 and 5

In C++ it gives:

```
int *MyFunc(int n) {
    static const int init[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};  // the initial array
    static int result[5];
    int& max = result[4];  // alias for the last value

    // copy init to result:
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) result[i] = init[i];

    // find the range of n
    for (;;) {
        if (n <= max) {
            break;
        }
        // multiply alternatively by 2 and by 5
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) result[i] *= 2; 
        if (n <= max) {
            break;
        }
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) result[i] *= 5;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Simple and compact...

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your first 2 arrays. You can do this in 3 steps.

Check if `number` is between `10^n and 5*(10^n)`. If it is, use the first array. If not, use the second array.

After that multiply each number by `10^n` for some `n` such that `10^n < number`.

This can be done by a for loop to check

Answer (score 1):

I would start with something like that:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> MyFunct(unsigned int number) {
  std::vector<unsigned int> numbers = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
  unsigned int factor = 1;
  while(number >= 10)
  {
    number /= 10;
    factor *= 10;
  }
  if(number >= 5)
  {
    factor *= 2;
  }

  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
  {
    numbers[i] *= factor;
  }

  return numbers;
}
```

You could also work with logarithm of base 10.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variant that does what you say it should do – display those outputs – rather than return an array.
It does not use any arrays at all.
(Note that the problem as stated contains overlapping intervals. I have assumed that the intervals are actually 0-5, 6-10, 11-50, 51-100, 101-500, 501-1000, and >1000.)

```
int factor(int x)
{
    if (x > 1000)
    {
        return 1000;
    }
    if (x > 500)
    {
        return 200;
    }
    if (x > 100)
    {
        return 100;
    }
    if (x > 50)
    {
        return 20;
    }
    if (x > 10)
    {
        return 10;
    }
    if (x > 5)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    return 1;
}


void display(int x)
{
    auto f = factor(x);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << f * i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> test = { 1, 6, 11, 52, 103, 504, 1005 };
    for (auto i: test)
    {
        display(i);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 4 6 8 10
10 20 30 40 50
20 40 60 80 100
100 200 300 400 500
200 400 600 800 1000
1000 2000 3000 4000 5000
```

And a variation of `factor` that uses a table instead of a long chain of conditionals:

```
int factor(int x)
{
    struct interval { int limit; int factor; };
    interval intervals[] = {{1000, 1000},
                            {500, 200},
                            {100, 100},
                            {50, 20},
                            {10, 10},
                            {5, 2}};
    for (auto i: intervals)
    {
        if (x > i.limit)
        {
            return i.factor;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```